# How to packaging WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have created API in WSO2 API manager 2.6.0 and its working as expected.
I was trying to understand how WSO2 internally does packaging all the component and how can I migrate the API from one environment to another.

I found couple of online documentation but it did not worked.
Can someone provide me the link or steps how can I deploy my WSO2 API from one system to another. 
Links I refereed are:

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Migrating+Applications+to+a+Different+Environment#50221ecf8cd345468aaeff8db19b2d08
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment

Comment: The link `migrating to a different environment` works for me. just use the version that corresponds to your server version: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Migrating+the+APIs+and+Applications+to+a+Different+Environment

Comment: What error did you get when trying to migrate the api?

Comment: I referred  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment  and able to do package using apimcli tool.